# Как вывести несколько точек на яндекс или гугл картах (имеются координаты)?

Tags: google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api, карты

Имеются в координаты точек - широта-долгота.
Как составить ссылку - чтобы по нажатию открывались все точки в Google maps или Yandex maps?

Вот так открывается одна точка на гугле (уже не работает): [https://www.google.ru/maps/place/59°57'01.2"N+30°18'59.0"E](https://www.google.ru/maps/place/59%C2%B057'01.2%22N+30%C2%B018'59.0%22E)
Как открыть если их несколько сразу надо?

UPD. ответом было

1) https://yandex.ru/maps/?pt=30.17870,59.85630~30.20716,59.82630~30.24734,59.84146&ll=30.3,59.9&z=11

2) https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?l=map&pt=37.6,55.6~37.601,55.6,78~37.602,55.6,pmgrs~37.603,55.6,pm2rdm~37.604,55.6,pmntl100~37.605,55.6,pmors23~37.606,55.6,flag~37.607,55.6,pm2ywl99~37.608,55.6,ya_ru

3) Для гугла, видимо, только так https://www.google.com/maps/dir/59.84213,30.39540/59.84213,30.39540
вроде бы как то так можно, но у меня не получилось с меткой https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=59.84213,30.39540 ([источник](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#search-action))

Answer (score 0):

Вот так это делается в Яндекс картах https://yandex.ru/maps/?pt=37.6%2C55.6~37.601%2C55.6&ll=37.601672%2C55.599641&z=17

Comment: Вот я нашла вот такую,  мне было супер возможность использовать разные цвета!. Но здесь выводится карта как картинка, не зумить,  не передвигать не дает. 
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/staticapi/1.x/dg/concepts/markers-docpage/

https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?l=map&pt=37.6,55.6~37.601,55.6,78~37.602,55.6,pmgrs~37.603,55.6,pm2rdm~37.604,55.6,pmntl100~37.605,55.6,pmors23~37.606,55.6,flag~37.607,55.6,pm2ywl99~37.608,55.6,ya_ru

Comment: Я не могу понять как использовать ваш варант? Например есть 3 точки (30.17870;59.85630) (30.20716;59.82630) (30.24734;59.84146) - как их вписать в пример?

Comment: И ещё большая печалька,  что я нажимаю на метку в браузере,  а она не раскрывается,  т. е.  я не могу даже посмотреть какая метка какие координаты имеет.

Comment: Вот так видимо https://yandex.ru/maps/?pt=30.17870,59.85630~30.20716,59.82630~30.24734,59.84146&ll=30.24734,59.84146&z=17

Comment: Спасибо большое! Получилось!
https://yandex.ru/maps/?pt=30.17870,59.85630~30.20716,59.82630~30.24734,59.84146&ll=30.3,59.9&z=11

Answer (score 0):

Для карт Гугл это может быть применено со следующим кодом:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Mashups with google.maps.Data</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
        .nicebox {
          position: absolute;
          text-align: center;
          font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
          font-size: 13px;
          z-index: 5;
          box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -4px #333;
          padding: 5px 10px;
          background: rgb(255,255,255);
          background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(245,245,245,1) 100%);
          border: rgb(229, 229, 229) 1px solid;
        }
        #controls {
          top: 10px;
          left: 110px;
          width: 360px;
          height: 45px;
        }
        #data-box {
          top: 10px;
          left: 500px;
          height: 45px;
          line-height: 45px;
          display: none;
        }
        #census-variable {
          width: 360px;
          height: 20px;
        }
        #legend { display: flex; display: -webkit-box; padding-top: 7px }
        .color-key {
          background: linear-gradient(to right,
            hsl(5, 69%, 54%) 0%,
            hsl(29, 71%, 51%) 17%,
            hsl(54, 74%, 47%) 33%,
            hsl(78, 76%, 44%) 50%,
            hsl(102, 78%, 41%) 67%,
            hsl(127, 81%, 37%) 83%,
            hsl(151, 83%, 34%) 100%);
          flex: 1;
          -webkit-box-flex: 1;
          margin: 0 5px;
          text-align: left;
          font-size: 1.0em;
          line-height: 1.0em;
        }
        #data-value { font-size: 2.0em; font-weight: bold }
        #data-label { font-size: 2.0em; font-weight: normal; padding-right: 10px; }
        #data-label:after { content: ':' }
        #data-caret { margin-left: -5px; display: none; font-size: 14px; width: 14px}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="controls" class="nicebox">
      <div>
      <select id="census-variable">
        <option value="https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/DP02_0066PE">Percent of population over 25 that completed high
        school</option>
        <option value="https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/DP05_0017E">Median age</option>
        <option value="https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/DP05_0001E">Total population</option>
        <option value="https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/DP02_0016E">Average family size</option>
        <option value="https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/DP03_0088E">Per-capita income</option>
      </select>
      </div>
      <div id="legend">
        <div id="census-min">min</div>
        <div class="color-key"><span id="data-caret">&#x25c6;</span></div>
        <div id="census-max">max</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="data-box" class="nicebox">
      <label id="data-label" for="data-value"></label>
      <span id="data-value"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var mapStyle = [{
        'stylers': [{'visibility': 'off'}]
      }, {
        'featureType': 'landscape',
        'elementType': 'geometry',
        'stylers': [{'visibility': 'on'}, {'color': '#fcfcfc'}]
      }, {
        'featureType': 'water',
        'elementType': 'geometry',
        'stylers': [{'visibility': 'on'}, {'color': '#bfd4ff'}]
      }];
      var map;
      var censusMin = Number.MAX_VALUE, censusMax = -Number.MAX_VALUE;

      function initMap() {

        // load the map
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 40, lng: -100},
          zoom: 4,
          styles: mapStyle
        });


        // set up the style rules and events for google.maps.Data
        map.data.setStyle(styleFeature);
        map.data.addListener('mouseover', mouseInToRegion);
        map.data.addListener('mouseout', mouseOutOfRegion);

        // wire up the button
        var selectBox = document.getElementById('census-variable');
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(selectBox, 'change', function() {
          clearCensusData();
          loadCensusData(selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value);
        });

        // state polygons only need to be loaded once, do them now
        loadMapShapes();

      }

      /** Loads the state boundary polygons from a GeoJSON source. */
      function loadMapShapes() {
        // load US state outline polygons from a GeoJson file
        map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/states.js', { idPropertyName: 'STATE' });

        // wait for the request to complete by listening for the first feature to be
        // added
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map.data, 'addfeature', function() {
          google.maps.event.trigger(document.getElementById('census-variable'),
              'change');
        });
      }

      /**
       * Loads the census data from a simulated API call to the US Census API.
       *
       * @param {string} variable
       */
      function loadCensusData(variable) {
        // load the requested variable from the census API (using local copies)
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', variable + '.json');
        xhr.onload = function() {
          var censusData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          censusData.shift(); // the first row contains column names
          censusData.forEach(function(row) {
            var censusVariable = parseFloat(row[0]);
            var stateId = row[1];

            // keep track of min and max values
            if (censusVariable < censusMin) {
              censusMin = censusVariable;
            }
            if (censusVariable > censusMax) {
              censusMax = censusVariable;
            }

            // update the existing row with the new data
            map.data
              .getFeatureById(stateId)
              .setProperty('census_variable', censusVariable);
          });

          // update and display the legend
          document.getElementById('census-min').textContent =
              censusMin.toLocaleString();
          document.getElementById('census-max').textContent =
              censusMax.toLocaleString();
        };
        xhr.send();
      }

      /** Removes census data from each shape on the map and resets the UI. */
      function clearCensusData() {
        censusMin = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        censusMax = -Number.MAX_VALUE;
        map.data.forEach(function(row) {
          row.setProperty('census_variable', undefined);
        });
        document.getElementById('data-box').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('data-caret').style.display = 'none';
      }

      /**
       * Applies a gradient style based on the 'census_variable' column.
       * This is the callback passed to data.setStyle() and is called for each row in
       * the data set.  Check out the docs for Data.StylingFunction.
       *
       * @param {google.maps.Data.Feature} feature
       */
      function styleFeature(feature) {
        var low = [5, 69, 54];  // color of smallest datum
        var high = [151, 83, 34];   // color of largest datum

        // delta represents where the value sits between the min and max
        var delta = (feature.getProperty('census_variable') - censusMin) /
            (censusMax - censusMin);

        var color = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          // calculate an integer color based on the delta
          color[i] = (high[i] - low[i]) * delta + low[i];
        }

        // determine whether to show this shape or not
        var showRow = true;
        if (feature.getProperty('census_variable') == null ||
            isNaN(feature.getProperty('census_variable'))) {
          showRow = false;
        }

        var outlineWeight = 0.5, zIndex = 1;
        if (feature.getProperty('state') === 'hover') {
          outlineWeight = zIndex = 2;
        }

        return {
          strokeWeight: outlineWeight,
          strokeColor: '#fff',
          zIndex: zIndex,
          fillColor: 'hsl(' + color[0] + ',' + color[1] + '%,' + color[2] + '%)',
          fillOpacity: 0.75,
          visible: showRow
        };
      }

      /**
       * Responds to the mouse-in event on a map shape (state).
       *
       * @param {?google.maps.MouseEvent} e
       */
      function mouseInToRegion(e) {
        // set the hover state so the setStyle function can change the border
        e.feature.setProperty('state', 'hover');

        var percent = (e.feature.getProperty('census_variable') - censusMin) /
            (censusMax - censusMin) * 100;

        // update the label
        document.getElementById('data-label').textContent =
            e.feature.getProperty('NAME');
        document.getElementById('data-value').textContent =
            e.feature.getProperty('census_variable').toLocaleString();
        document.getElementById('data-box').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('data-caret').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('data-caret').style.paddingLeft = percent + '%';
      }

      /**
       * Responds to the mouse-out event on a map shape (state).
       *
       * @param {?google.maps.MouseEvent} e
       */
      function mouseOutOfRegion(e) {
        // reset the hover state, returning the border to normal
        e.feature.setProperty('state', 'normal');
      }

    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Источник: **[документация Гугл Combining and Visualizing Multiple Data Sources](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/combining-data)**.

Comment: Я вставила этот текст в html файл, вставила api key - этот файл отображает совсем другое (население по штатам сша)
мне же нужно было чтобы открылася координатная метка!

Comment: Ну, разумеется там надо изменять значения в соответствии с вашими потребностями.